# Trying to use grunt-contrib-requirejs to minify all JS to one file

Tags: requirejs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-requirejs

I have the following directory structure (relevant bits only):

```
app
 - build
   - script.js
 - js
   - lib
     - require.js
     - jquery-1.10.2.js
   - app.js
 - index.html
Gruntfile.js
```

#### Gruntfile.js contains the following:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    var gruntConfig = {
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        requirejs: {
            compile: {
                options: {
                    name: 'app',
                    baseUrl: 'app/assets/js',
                    out: 'app/assets/build/script.js',
                    include:  ['lib/require'],

                    uglify: {
                        // beautify: true,
                        defines: {
                            DEBUG: ['name', 'false']
                        }
                    },

                    paths: {
                        jquery: "lib/jquery-1.10.2"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    };

    grunt.initConfig(gruntConfig);

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-requirejs');

};
```

#### app.js contains the following:

```
require(['jquery'], function ($) {
    // Do stuff
});
```

How do I set it up so that it copies *all* the JavaScript needed into build/script.js, not just app.js and require.js when I tell it to (erroring when I try to use jQuery)? I also want to be able to add modules without adding them to my Gruntfile, just by adding them to script.js.

Comment: Could you try updating the include statement to `include: ['lib/**/*.js']` and see if that works?

Comment: I changed some code and then I changed it back again and now it works. I am utterly confused, and while this problem seems to be fixed, I do not have the solution (I'm assuming it didn't just happen randomly).

Answer (score 1):

You can have a mainConfigFile defined and inside config file have paths to you lib code like this

Contents of gruntfile:

```
requirejs: {
  compile: {
    options: {
      baseUrl: "app/js/",
      mainConfigFile: app/config.js",
      out: "build/script.js",
      name: "config"
    }
  }
}
```

Contents of config file:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    lib: "<path to>/js/lib",
    jquery: "<path to>/js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min",
    .
    and particular file required
    .
  }
```

Requirejs will add the contents of all path files to the optimized code.

Comment: This didn't work for me, it's only showing the config file in output

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your options object:

```
findNestedDependencies: true
```

This way grunt-contrib-requirejs (actually just requirejs) will find whatever dependencies are listed on your config file.

Hope it works for you.